# matTootip on Safari - How to prevent matTootip from blocking input-text on Safari?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'am using a [`matTooltip`](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview) from Angular Material for an input field... the input is a kind of overlapped on Safari, so that I can't type in it.

I have been changing the position of the toolTip, but id didn't help.

```
<input type="text" matInput matTooltip="Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula." matTooltipPosition="right" formControlName="password" name="xxx" #inputXxxx>
```

The toolTip is working fine on all other browser.

This is how the Input filed looks like then:

[image]

Any idea how to work around this issue.

Comment: What does the input look like when hovered? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Edric: Screenshot has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed. The solution was in a way simple... I did add the attribute: `matTooltip` in the `mat-form-field` instead of in the `input` itself.

```
<mat-form-field matInput matTooltip="Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula.">
    <input type="text" matTooltipPosition="right" formControlName="password" name="xxx" #inputXxxx>
</mat-form-field>
```