# Problems with md-tooltip and safari

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following html code

```
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="number" 
              [(ngModel)]="cons.failPercent" [ngModelOptions]="{ 
              standalone: true}"
              mdTooltip="Typically valves can be repaired three times 
              before they need to be replaced"
              mdTooltipPosition="right"
              autofocus/>
            </div>
```

I am using Angular 4 and the tooltip is preventing typing into the input box in Safari, but in Chrome it works fine. Is there a way to have the tooltip still work in Safari?

Comment: Could you please vote me/my answer up, if my solution did work for you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did face this issue once... you have to remove **`mdTooltip`** from **`input`** and use it as attribute in the **`div`** tag, then it will work:

```
<div class="input-group" mdTooltip="Typically valves can be repaired three times before they need to be replaced">
   <input class="form-control" type="number"[ 
          [(ngModel)]="cons.failPercent" [ngModelOptions]="{ 
          standalone: true}"
          mdTooltipPosition="right"
          autofocus/>
</div>
```

and I would also use **`matTooltip`** instead of: **`mdTooltip`**.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811893/mattootip-on-safari-how-to-prevent-mattootip-from-blocking-input-text-on-safar) you can find my old question